# Advice on cooling second story cape cod

Tags: hvac

I own a home in the NE that has no central AC or heat and now that summer is in full swing, the humidity is posing a problem to say the least. The house is a two story cape cod with 2 bedrooms on the first floor and the second floor is completely open floor plan with two "bedrooms" and an open bathroom. It needs finishing but that's not my concern at the moment. The upstairs sees a significant amount of hot air during the day right now, with temps around 100*. There's no attic access anywhere and only one ceiling fan upstairs to circulate air. At the beginning of the year I paid someone to replace all the ridge vents throughout the house, over the garage and the 2 dormers. It doesn't seem to have helped at all because the ceiling temp is still extremely high even well into the evening.

I'm looking for advice on what to attack first. My thought for later this year or next is to install two tri-zone mini split heat exchangers and use that to cool and heat the house as much as possible. We have supplemental heat from a wood stove In basement. Wondering if the mini split will be sufficient even if sized properly. Or if I should start somewhere else. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have pics of the house?

Answer (score 1):

Ceiling fans don't cool a space, they just make it feel cooler to a person in the space.  Fans blowing out of upstairs windows would help dissipate the heat out of the house. Attic fans used to be common for locations that weren't hot all day and this would be much cheaper than installing split or central air.

Certainly insulating the walls and ceiling will help.  You should do this regardless of whether or not you install air conditioning.  I would think that air conditioning would be available to cool the space with almost any load; with no insulation you will just be spending money on excess electricity.  That said, I don't know your cooling season, and what the payback would be for insulation improvements.  Consider an energy audit by your power company.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do it, is to insulate, followed by mini-split heat exchanger.

Since you have no access to the attic, to insulate the roof, next best would be to insulate the ceiling.

For that you would use 4 inch thick rigid foam of your choice and attach it to the ceiling.

Comment: Could I just cut an opening and have someone blow in more insulation? I don't think it's just an attic problem though, I think the entire roof line doesn't have the proper insulation. My IR gun picks up every corner and edge of the up stairs ceiling as a heat loss/gain source. I wonder if I should remove the drywall and see what R value insulation is up there.

Comment: Remove the drywall then add the foam and drywall over it?

Comment: After researching some more I think our problem is lack of insulation and ventilation in knee walls.

Comment: foam insulation installed on the ceiling would be quite the eyesore.